# How can I assign the 'Close on Escape-key press' behavior to all WPF windows within a project?

Tags: wpf, escaping, command, key-bindings, windows

Is there any straightforward way of telling the whole WPF application to react to Escape key presses by attempting to close the currently focused widow? It is not a great bother to manually setup the command- and input bindings but I wonder if repeating this XAML in all windows is the most elegant approach?

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="Close" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="Close" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Any constructive suggestions welcome!

Comment: Similar question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691713/how-to-close-a-window-in-wpf-on-a-escape-key

Comment: Use IsCancel standard property. Example https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692796/591656

Answer (score 33, accepted):

All I can suggest to improve on that is to remove the need for an event handler by binding to a static command instance.

Note: this will only work in .NET 4 onwards as it requires the ability to bind to the `KeyBinding` properties.

First, create a command that takes a Window as a parameter and calls `Close` within the `Execute` method:

```
public class CloseThisWindowCommand : ICommand
{
    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //we can only close Windows
        return (parameter is Window);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (this.CanExecute(parameter))
        {
            ((Window)parameter).Close();
        }
    }

    #endregion

    private CloseThisWindowCommand()
    {

    }

    public static readonly ICommand Instance = new CloseThisWindowCommand();
}
```

Then you can bind your `KeyBinding` to the static `Instance` property:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Escape" Command="{x:Static local:CloseThisWindowCommand.Instance}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

I don't know that this is necessarily *better* than your approach, but it does mean marginally less boilerplate at the top of every `Window` and that you don't need to include an event handler in each

Comment: can this lead to memory leaks since the singleton has an `EventHandler`?

Comment: It shouldn't do but as we don't really care about the `CanExecute` functionality you could safeguard against it by having `CanExecute` always return true and replace the `CanExecuteChanged` handler with empty attachment implementations (e.g. `public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add {} remove {} }`)

Answer (score 24):

Or you could just add a button with Cancel as text and set `IsCancel = True`. Then Escape will work as default command to close.

Comment: not always ideal but still like the suggestion. Simple enough.

Answer (score 2):

create `RoutedUICommand` like below

```
 private static RoutedUICommand EscUICommand = new RoutedUICommand("EscBtnCommand"
       , "EscBtnCommand"
       , typeof(WindowName)
       , new InputGestureCollection(new InputGesture[] 
           { new KeyGesture(Key.Escape, ModifierKeys.None, "Close") }));
```

and add it command binding in constructor

```
CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(EscUICommand, (sender, e) => { this.Hide(); }));
```

Comment: This works quite nicely, and when you already have a class for your window, it keeps everything right there.

Comment: If you have to write code behind you could just write in constructor:  PreviewKeyDown += (s,e) => { if (e.Key == Key.Escape) Close() ;};

Answer (score 1):

On `Window`s shown with `ShowDialog()` you can use:

```
<!-- Button to close on Esc -->
<Button IsCancel="True" Width="0" Height="0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use PreviewKeyDown Event

```
PreviewKeyDown="UserControl_PreviewKeyDown"
```

Code behind call you close command

```
private void UserControl_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
            {
                _vm.OnCloseCommand(sender);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way is to use attached properties

Bellow is a gist code:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/meziantou/1e98d7d7aa6aa859d916.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Preview` events happen quite early. If you have a control that should take the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key for its own purposes, stealing it at the window level may be too aggressive.

Instead you can handle it only if nothing else wants to:

```cs
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);

    if (!e.Handled && e.Key == Key.Escape && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.None)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

None of above worked for me, except Kai's.
I modified his answer: I added 'btn_close.IsCancel = true;' to constructor. SettingsWindow is my second window, and main window is (default) MainWindow.

```
  public partial class SettingsWindow : Window {
    public SettingsWindow() {
      InitializeComponent();
      btn_close.IsCancel = true;
    }
    private void btn_close_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      this.Close();
    }
  }
```

Hope it helps,

Simon
S love nia