# WPF keydown not capturing escape?

Tags: c#, wpf, keypress, keydown

xaml file

```
PreviewKeyDown="Window_KeyDown"
```

.cs file

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

KeyPreview is set to true, although the message box doesn't appear for the ESC key. (the message box does show for other "normal" keys such as 0-9 and a-z). How would I fix this or find a way to trigger something on ESC?

---

EDIT

---

Win.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WindowsFormsApplication5.Win"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         WindowStyle="None" 
         PreviewKeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
</Window>
```

Win.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Win : Window
{
    public Win()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
        if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Win scrn = new Win();
        scrn.Show();
    }
}
```

Hopefully this should clear up any issues, sorry for being unclear about this.

Comment: Why are you using a Windows Forms `MessageBox` with WPF?

Comment: Duplicate question, already answered in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691713/how-to-close-a-window-in-wpf-on-a-escape-key

Comment: I don't know, simplest way I knew of displaying a popup message, is this really relevant?

Comment: Use `System.Windows.MessageBox` instead?

Comment: Where do you have that `PreviewKeyDown` event attached to? To your window? Then it should work; and it does work for me. Unless you have another handler that consumes the key event and cancels it.

Comment: Works for me..can you reproduce this issue in a simple wpf application ?

Comment: :) Does the `Esc` key on your keyboard work?

Comment: Just throwing in some Form1 code does not clear up issues.  Voting to close.

Comment: @Frisbee I made a new project, entered the code in here to the separate files. No more code is used and I get the exact same problem, very easy to reproduce, I'm sorry if this isn't enough information, but really; it should be.

Comment: Can you upload your solution somewhere?

Comment: @poke I have no solution thats the thing?

Comment: Not problem solution but Visual Studio solution (the project files and stuff)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Close a Window in WPF on a escape key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691713/how-to-close-a-window-in-wpf-on-a-escape-key)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe WPF MessageBox is *relevant*

This works just fine for me

```
<Window PreviewKeyDown="wPreviewKeyDown"

private void wPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
        this.Close();
}
```

Do you have another control that is possibly handling the event?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running the WPF dialog from within a WinForms form, the Escape key appears to be filtered out. Here is a fix:

```
var wpfWindow = new SomeWpfWindow();
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wpfWindow);
wpfWindow.Show();
```